# How to find index method using loop. not with inbuilt method

Tags: python

How to implement index method using loop.

`sub_str` is found in `my_str` then it will print the index of first occurrence of first character of matching string in `my_str`.

Input:

```
my_str = 'Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers.',
sub_str = 'Pickl'
```

Output

```
29
```

Code is below

```
main="Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers"
sub="Pickl"
t = main.split()
for i in range (0,len(t)):
    match = True
    if sub in t[i]:
        print(i)
```

My output is `6`

Expected Out is `29`

Comment: What does the expected 29 represent? At present your code is giving the index of the word in the sentence that includes “Pickl”, which is 6.

Comment: Ah I see, 29 is the index of the start letter of the substring. `splt()` defaults to splitting a string where there are spaces, not individual letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is:

```
my_str = "Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers."
sub_str = "Pickl"

for i in range(0,len(my_str)):
    if my_str[i:i+len(sub_str)] == sub_str:
        print(i)
```

I haven't tried it yet so it might need some tweakings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the start index of the substring in the input string (which would be 29). The `splt()` method defaults to splitting a string where there are spaces; into words, not individual letters. That is why you get an output of 6.

You can find the start index of a substring with the `find()` method:

```
output = main.find(sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 nested loops

```
def myindex(main,sub):
    for kk in range (len(main) - len(sub)):
        match = True
        for ii in range(len(sub)):
            if main[kk+ii] != sub[ii]:
                match = False
                break
        if match:
            return kk
    return -1
```

---

```
>>> myindex("Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers","Pickl")
29
```

Answer (score 0):

`6` is the index of an element that matches with your substring in the array after splitting the array into chunks of words if you want to find the index of the substring you can use the `find()` method in your case it would be:

```
main="Peter Piper Picked A Peck Of Pickled Peppers"
sub="Pickl"
t = main.find(sub)
print(t)
```

Here `t` will be `29`